# After Xamarin upgrading APK file contains x86_64 and its size has grown

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

After I did upgrade to last version of xamarin studio and one of lastest xamarin.android I have found that size of application has grown from 25 MB to 28 MB and while I was loading apk on Google play console I saw that it also including x86_64 that never seen before.

Now it contains
armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64 in Google play apk properties screen.
May be it is the reason of apk size growing.  My last upgrading were at January of 2016 and now I have Xamarin.Android Version: 6.1.2.21.

So, please answer why there is added x86_64, If I didn't add it at Build section of running project.
Thanks in Advance!

===Xamarin Studio Community ===
Version 6.1.1 (build 15)
Installation UUID: dd5f86d4-a3f3-4a5e-b904-b27d934f5a7f

Runtime:
    Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.42000
    GTK+ 2.24.26 (Light theme)
    GTK# 2.12.38

=== NuGet ===
Version: 3.4.3.0

=== Xamarin.Android ===
Version: 6.1.2.21 (Xamarin Studio Community)

Answer (score 1):

If you are worrying about APK size, I would suggest that you enable the option to create an APK per ABI. This way you shave off a lot of overhead compared to cramming all the ABI's into one APK.

This is what my build settings look like:

[image: Packaging options]

Then I have selected the following ABI's:

[image: Selected ABI's]

Why an additional ABI was added to your package is unclear, it could be that it is something the Xamarin build defaults to now or maybe a bug.

If it is indeed a bug, you should report it on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: This is an excellent answer, though I wanted to note that since the user is in Xamarin Studio the equivalent settings would be found in **Project Options > Build > Android Build** under the "General" & "Advanced" tabs respectively.

Comment: The problem is that I am didn't select x86_64 and x86, only three armeabi, armeai-v7a, arm64-v8a. But after creating apk and loading at google play it stay contain additionally x86_64. Who is adding it without my selecting?

Comment: Can you unpack the APK and see if it is really the case?